# Android Notification Schedule

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I am trying to show a popup message on some specific date and time. Say for example a user set a event. I want to remind him on that specific date and time that he is having a even pending. I saw lots of ways to do this with alarm manager, android service like and I am confused which one will be the best to do this. I really don't want to open my app on that notification. Just a alert box is enough for this. And even if my app is not running or after setting event user may reboot his device but still I want receive my notification  . Any idea which will be the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really don't want to open my app on that notification

If you do not want to open your app on clicking the notification, do not add a `PendingIntent` to your `Notification`.

> And even if my app is not running or after setting event user may
>   reboot his device but still I want receive my notification .

For this, you will need a `Service` that runs at startup and executes the your logic to determine what events to show to the user.